# Problema con ngfor en ionic

Tags: angular, ionic

Buen dia, estoy consumiendo una api que realice en laravel y hasta el momento si estoy trayendo los datos bien, ya que los probé por la consola. Ahora el problema es que al momento de generar unas cards en ionic para mostrar los datos que estoy consumiendo no me muestra nada, todo esto lo hago con un ngfor, al momento que lo quito se muestra la card de ejemplo.

código y muestra

componente post-list

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header> Usuarios </ion-list-header>
    <app-post-item *ngFor=" let item of usaurios" [usuario]="item">
    </app-post-item>
</ion-list>
```

componente post-item

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=2" />
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>I'm a big deal</h3>
        <p>Listen, I've had a pretty messed up day...</p>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Almomento que le quito el `*ngFor=" let item of usaurios" [usuario]="item"` en el componete post-list ahora si me arroja esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no tengo claro que estoy realizando mal o si tengo un erro...

logica
user.service

```
export class UserService {
    public url: String = environment.url;
    public usuarios$ = new Subject<Usuario[]>(); 
    public usuario$ = new Subject<Usuario>();

    public usuarios: Usuario[] = [];
    public usuario: Usuario;
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
    all$(): Observable<Usuario[]> {
        return this.usuarios$.asObservable();
    }
    all(): Observable<any> {
        this.usuarios = [];
        return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.url + 'usuario').pipe(
            map ((res: any[]) => {
                Array.from(res).forEach((item: any) => {
                    this.usuario = new Usuario();
                    this.usuario.set(item);
                    this.usuarios.push(this.usuario);
                });
                this.usuarios$.next(this.usuarios);
                console.log(res);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

post-list.component

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
    public usaurios: Usuario[] = [];
    public usuario: Usuario;
    public usuarioSubscription = new Subscription();

    constructor(
        public userservice: UserService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.usuarioSubscription = this.userservice.all$().subscribe((res: Usuario[])=>{
            this.usaurios = res;
        });
        this.userservice.all().subscribe(res => {
            console.log('Listo...');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El ngFor parece estar bien formado, podrias incluir el codigo de tu typescript (.ts) para entender tu logica?, por otro lado, sugiero coloques algun console.log en el lugar donde estes cargando tus datos, por ejemplo si usas Angular, tipicamente eso iria en el ngOnInit

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo de la logica, igual lo paso hice proba con console.log para ver si mostraba los datos por consola y efectivamente